# Squid with whitelist and redirect

Tags: debian, redirect, squid, whitelist

I managed to setup Squid3 on a Debian Squeeze 6.0 server in trasparent mode with iptables nat redirection.

All requests on port 80 are correctly redirected to squid and then compared with a whitelist file.

All requests to sites not covered by the whitelist are sent to the custom ERR_ACCESS_DENIED page. This page contains a simple login form.

So, when a site is blocked, the user has the ability to add that site to the whitelist.

I've created a very simple PHP script which takes the URL (with a regex), adds it to the whitelist and restarts squid.

At this point, i would to redirect the browser to the new authorized site, with a simple

```
$your_url = http://www.example.com;
header("Location: $your_url");
```

but squid gives me an ERR_INVALID_URL page trying to retrive

```
(null)://www.example.com
```

If I try to type the url in the address bar, the site is correctly served.

I've tried to set a timeout in PHP before redirect, but even with a 1 minute timeout, the redirect fails.
In the mean time, typing the url in the address bar works ok.

Any clue?

**UPDATE** Problem easly solved switching to Squid 2.7

Squid3 bug [here](http://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2976)

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved switching to Squid 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar project called parentwall. I got around the issue by using squid -k reconfigure instead of restarting squid. You can do the same thing with the rc scripts.

Restarting squid takes forever and is unnecessary to reload the white list.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but it might be easier here to simply do a javascript redirect.  So instead of trying to do a redirect with PHP simply return a page which has some javascript.

It is a bit less elegant, but it will probably be easier.

Comment: Javascript doesn't solve the problem. It is a squid bug documented [here](http://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2976).

Comment: Given the way I read that, it seems like javascript could solve the problem if you put a sufficient delay in place to allow for the squid reconfigure to complete.  In any case, you should add an answer and mark that as accepted.

Comment: The behavior is really strange. I've tried to put a delay in javascript as in php (1 minute) or print a link in the success page. The null bug appeared in both cases.